# Salesforce Mobile App Security - More Control on Copy/Paste

Tags: salesforce-mobile-app

Salesforce has help document on Mobile app security, which outlines additional attributes to control copy/paste, see link at the bottom.

I believe, setting custom attribute **DISABLE_EXTERNAL_PASTE** on connected app is a blanket option, i.e. it would disable copy/paste completely.

We're looking for an option to allow copy/paste to other trusted mobile apps i.e. outlook or teams etc. Has anyone achieved this?

[Control Access and Security for the Salesforce Mobile App] (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.salesforce_app_security.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

Clipboards come in two flavors: public and private. The public clipboard is shared across all apps, while a private clipboard exists only within a single app. There is no OS concept of a shared clipboard that can whitelist or blacklist apps from accessing a particular clipboard. You have to choose which one you're going to use, and accept the limitations of that choice.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for your input. I used copy/paste feature as one example. Ability to "Share" with other apps is another feature.

Any idea around putting wrapper around Salesforce Mobile App?

Comment: @SudeepGhag As I said, this is functionality provided by the OS, not the app. The security model of mobile OSes don't permit this level of authority. You can choose to share, or not, you can provide targets, and you can exclude your own components (e.g. so you don't Share with yourself), but you can't choose to not share to other targets the OS presents. This is also true for copy-paste, etc.